# Use different data for production and develop firebase sites

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

I have a CI/DC pipeline with google cloud build triggers that deploy my code to different sites depending on which branch I push to. The develop site is a live test - the final check before I merge to master, which triggers a deploy of master to the production site.

Currently, both sites use the same firebase Firestore db, and any document changed on the develop site will also be changed on the production site.

What I want to avoid is creating another firebase project to push the develop code to with a different database, because that means I need a separate set of credentials and would copy the same functions over to the new project every time I change them. That's not maintainable and is a lot of work.

What I would like is some way for the develop site to only have access to part of the firestore database, and the production site to have access to another part.

How do people do this? Is it even possible? Is there a better way? One alternative I can think of is using authentication and creating separate accounts for testing with different access permissions, but this seems a work-around and not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do sounds like a lot more hassle than [using multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects), which is the documented and strongly preferred solution.  Putting everything in one project is a huge anti-pattern in Firebase and Google Cloud, and it will cause you more problems in the long run, in addition to increasing the risk of catastrophic failure if you manage to misconfigure something in that one project.

It's perfectly maintainable to have multiple projects like this, if you apply some scripting to automate the work.  This is very common, and I strongly suggest thinking through how this would work for you.

You CI/CD pipeline could definitely check out your updates from source control and deploy them to whatever other project environments you have set up.  It's very common to manage different credentials and configurations for use in CI/CD.